# How to plotting line graph with different linestyle using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, linestyle

I have data of minimum ping time in normal condition and in DOS simulation so the data will be different. I still newbie as data scientist and only can make visualization from the data like this.

[image]

The code to build the picture above is this

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8), dpi=300)
df_min.plot(kind='line', 
            x='no', 
            y=['min1','min2'], 
            color=['blue','red'],
            ax=ax)
plt.xlabel('Attempt amount')
plt.ylabel('Min')
plt.title('Comparison of Min Value')
plt.legend(['Normal','Syn Flood'])
```

Is anyone know how to change the linestyle, I mean the blue is still using this '-' but the red can changed become '--' or 'x'?

I was trying to inject the df_min.plot with`linestyle=['-','--']`

But got error, is anybody have idea?

I will upload the data into my drive, so you can download it, here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qqOXguKIg1D-axZfaRuGkQNHTTgynQ9a/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks!

Comment: `df_min.plot(kind='line', x='no', y=['min1', 'min2'], color=['blue', 'red'], style=['-', '--'], ax=ax)`

Comment: The property is `style` not `linestyle`. Please refer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: @dm2 thank you, well I already read it, but not really understand

Comment: @HenryEcker yeah I got it, I write wrong thing, will you write it in answer page, I will really happy to flag your answer to be the most helpful solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
df_min = pd.read_csv(csvpath)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8), dpi=300)
df_min.plot(kind='line',  #'line', 
            style='-.',
            x='no', 
            y=['min1','min2'], 
            color=['blue','red'],
            ax=ax)
plt.xlabel('Attempt amount')
plt.ylabel('Min')
plt.title('Comparison of Min Value')
plt.legend(['Normal','Syn Flood'])
```

Try running this.

Comment: thank you for answering the question, what I want before is to make the style different, and I just know the problem, it's the `linestyle` not `style` but thanks for answering, I will vote up yours